# How to interpret result of recvfrom (raw socket)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, packet-sniffers

I'm developing a custom packet sniffer in Python3.
It does not have to be platform independant. I'm using Linux.
The method I use is to recvfrom() from a socket (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW).
It works fine but I have problem with info returned by recvfrom().
recvfrom() returns a tuple with 5 components.
Example: ('eno1', 2054, 0, 1, b'\x00!\x9b\x16\xfa\xd1')
How do I interpret the last 4 components?
Where is it documented?
I prefer not to use libpcap or scapy.
OK! here's a code fragment:
    s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))
    ...
    packet,pktAdr = s.recvfrom(65565)
    print( 'pktAdr:'+str(pktAdr))

Thanks!

Comment: Where is it documented? How about on docs.python.org? Also, you need to show your code if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented on  docs.python.org so I did some research.
I'm now in a position to answer to myself.

The tuple returned by recvfrom is similar to a sockaddr_ll structure returned by the Linux kernel.
The tuple contains 5 components:
 - [0]: interface name (eg 'eth0')
 - [1]: protocol at the physical level (defined in linux/if_ether.h)
 - [2]: packet type (defined in linux/if_packet.h)
 - [3]: ARPHRD (defined in linux/if_arp.h)
 - [4]: physical address
The example provided in  the question can be decoded into:
 - 'eno1'
 - ARP protocol (0x806)
 - Incoming packet
 - Ethernet frame
 - MAC address
In case of a WiFi interface in monitor mode, the [3] element would be 803 (meaning 'IEEE802.11 + RadioTap header').

Hope this will help somebody

Comment: how did you get 5 elemets tuple if it should return (bytes, address)?

Comment: Sockets with SOCK_RAW option are poorly documented (in Linux and Python). Here's my understanding (beware I'm not a kernel specialist). In SOCK_RAW mode, the packet returned by kernel is prefixed with a SLL structure (also known as Linux Cooked Interface). In Python, the SLL is removed from the packet and the SLL information is decoded and provided in an array (described in my answer). Thus your Python program will receive 2 elements (packet and SLL array[5]).